# How to embed source code into aar in gradle?

Tags: gradle

Afaik it's possible to embed the source code into a Java library.
So when someone uses the library in an IDE he can easily see the source code. This makes developing easier.

I want to do this with a Android library (.aar file) in gradle.

Is there a gradle option for this?

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.